# UDP conformation, is it possible?

Tags: python, udp, tello-drone

I am using python to send a udp command to a Tello edu drone. The problem I am having is that the drone doesn’t read anything past the 1st command i send.

Is there are a way to confirm sending the UDP so the drone reads it at all cost. Or send the command until the drone reads it?

I tried sending the 2nd command repeatedly which works however at certain times it repeats that command more than once.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is an unreliable protocol, i.e. sending a message is basically fire and forget. Any acknowledgements for received messages or retransmissions in case packets are not acknowledged need to be implemented at the application level - both in sender and receiver.

If the protocol used to communicate with the drone does not provide any way for reliable communication, then one cannot enforce reliable communication  from the sender side.